# DataGridViewRowEventsArgs - 'Cancel' Property is missing

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working with a DataGridView on a newly installed VS2022.

I'm trying to cancel a row delete event:

```
    private void dataGridView1_UserDeleteRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
      {
         if (...)
          { e.Cancel; }
      }
```

The problem is that there is no 'Cancel' property for event object 'e'. Going bezerk trying to figure out why. What am I missing?

Comment: Where did you get that signature?  It looks like it's supposed to be `DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs`

Comment: It was auto generated after selecting the corresponding event for the control. If I manually change it to DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs, then it complains about the missing overload delegate for this event.

Comment: Weird.  Microsoft has it documented [with the DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.userdeletingrow?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)  I'll try to test it myself.

Comment: Sorry, I see it now.  The event you want is `UserDeletingRow`.

Comment: After opening the documentation link you posted, I've realized my mistake. I'm using 'UserDeletedRow' (event already happened, so there is nothing to cancel), while I need 'UserDeletingRow' - which uses DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs. Need a break from staring at code for so long, my eyes didn't catch it. Thanks again for your suggestions.

Comment: Yes, looks like you realized it almost immediately as I was typing my comment. thank you!